# UWP Image to Bitmap Conversion

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to convert an image to a bitmap in order to use AForge filters. On MSN website i saw that Bitmap has an image contructor but when i try it it doesn't work. This is the code i have :

```
                     Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image1);
```

Comment: what's the data type of image1?  also what do you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: image1 is a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image, and doing as above tells me that Bitmap doesn't contain a constructor, which contradicts with what they've said on their site.

Comment: Have you tried a direct cast? `Bitmap bitmap = image1 as Bitmap`

Comment: Yes, it gives me this error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0039 Cannot convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion MyFirstJob C:\Users\Robert\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyFirstJob\MyFirstJob\MainPage.xaml.cs 69 Active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert directly between `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image`.

Think of AForge as using the `Bitmap` class, while UWP uses the [WritableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap) for its images. You'll need to find a way to convert between the two.

Take a look at the [Usage](https://github.com/cureos/aforge#usage) section of this [Aforge.Net library](https://github.com/cureos/aforge), which provides one way of doing things (Quoted):

```
// Use explicit operator to convert from WriteableBitmap to Bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)aWriteableBitmapObject;

// Apply one or more filter functions on the Bitmap object
var filter1 = AForge.Imaging.Filters.Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.RMY;
bitmap = filter1.Apply(bitmap);
var filter2 = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.CannyEdgeDetector();
filter2.ApplyInPlace(bitmap);

// Use explicit operator to convert back from Bitmap to WriteableBitmap
aWriteableBitmapObject = (WriteableBitmap)bitmap;
```

Comment: Can I see the  Aforge.Net source?

Comment: Here's a [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/aforge/source/default/source) to the official Aforge.Net source from their website

Comment: Thx but vs say `aWriteableBitmapObject = (WriteableBitmap)bitmap;` the Bitmap  cant cast to WriteableBitmap